# Ordenar os filhos em consulta Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou com problema em fazer uma ordenação em uma consulta onde tenho que ordenar os filhos pelo o ID, Segue o Fonte.

```
public Grid GetByOrderGridData(long id)
{
    var query = from c in context.Set<Grid>()
                where c.Id == id
                orderby c.GridDatas.OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                select c;
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

o fonte compila sem problema mas ao consultar.

> {"DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.\r\nNome do parâmetro: key"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem duas opções viáveis:

1. Ordernar os dados depois de consultar

   ```
   var query = from c in context.Set<Grid>()
               where c.Id == id
               select c;


   var retorno = query.FirstOrDefault();
   retorno.GridDatas = retorno.GridDatas.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

   return retorno;
   ```
2. Executar uma *query* separada para trazer os elementos filhos:

   ```
   var elemento = context.context.Set<Grid>().FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
   var entry = context.Entry(elemento);

   entry.Collection(e => e.GridData).Query().OrderBy(c => c.Id).Load();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é esta:

```
public Grid GetByOrderGridData(long id)
{
        var query = from c in context.Set<Grid>()
                    where c.Id == id
                    orderby c.Id 
                    select c;
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Se você quiser pegar de ordem decrescente basta fazer:

```
orderby c.Id descending
```

Você também pode fazer assim:

```
public Grid GetByOrderGridData(long id)
{
     return = (from c in context.Set<Grid>()
              where c.Id == id
              select c).OrderBy(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

E também pode fazer usando expressão lambda:

```
public Grid GetByOrderGridData(long id)
{
     return context.Set<Grid>().Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).OrderBy(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: a ordenação tem que ser pelo o filho de GridDatas, na sua solução ela esta retornando a ordenação pelo o pai o grid no caso e o alias 'C' na consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Eu resumiria tudo em.

```
public Grid GetByOrderGridData(long id)
{
    var grid = (from c in context.Set<Grid>()
                where c.Id == id
                orderby c.
                select c
              ).FirstOrDefault();

    if(grid != null)
        grid = grid.GridDatas.OrderBy(p => p.Id);

    return grid;
}
```

Uma vez que você vai ao banco usando o `FirstOrDefault`. você tem os dados em memoria é pode trabalha, uma observação aqui é que o `FirstOrDefault` retorna NULL como Default e se isso não for tratado seu `grid.GridDatas.OrderBy` retornara erro.